# applicationWillEnterForeground / applicationDidEnterBackground working together

Tags: objective-c, ios, background

I have a decryption and encryption method in my app. When the app enters the background, a file is encrypted. If the app entered the foreground, the file will be decrypted. Thats the main story. Both parts take some time and a lot of memory. In the background, Im doing something like that.

```
encryptionTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
    // Wwe took too long. Stop task.
}];
```

In the applicationWillEnterForeground, Im doing the following:

```
if (encryptionTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:encryptionTaskId];
}
```

I think that works well. But my problem is when someone clicks the `home` button during the `applicationWillEnterForeground` is decrypting my file. Again the `applicationDidEnterBackground` is starting, but my decrypting is not finished. What is the best way to handle that. Is it possible to also wait until the foreground finished?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to detect if the file is currently being accessed or being encrypted / decrypted? If so, create a timer to do the encryption / decryption again in a few seconds after the previous method has stopped.

UPDATE:

Please see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28 you should be able to use [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a). Which will buy you extra time to finish processing before your app moves to the background.

UPDATE 2:

Make sure `encryptionTaskId` is an instance variable

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    encryptionTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
        encryptionTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
    encryptionTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Then in `applicationDidEnterForeground` you will want to check if `encryptionTaskId` is still working and if so create a timer to try again shortly to decode it.

Comment: Probably I could do that, but seems to be not the best approach? I dont understand the whole process: It seems to be that my decryption still finishs, when the the user press the home button during the decryption in applicationWillEnterForeground. Is that correct?

Comment: And I also think its not possible/allowed to have a timer in the applicationDidEnterBackground?

Comment: Im using exactly this method. You can see that in my code above. But my problem is, that when Im pressing the home button and instantly press on the app again, the watchdog is killing my app because it takes too long to start the app (I guess...)

Comment: thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. I already tried it with that, but I had problems when I did something like: click on app, go to background, click on app again. I then had to wait in the applicationDidEnterBackground until the decryption was finished, but then I blocked the main thread and the app needed too long to start und the watchdog killed it. At the moment im trying a new approach with NSOperationQueue.